# Actualizar div automaticamente en template de django

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando desarrollar un dashboard con django que muestre notificaciones y actualice su estado automaticamente.

Estuve viendo que con Ajax y Jquery puedo actulizar div sin problema...

Pero estoy teniendo problemas con los templates pues uso Django.

Aca mi codigo

**View de Django para mostrar en loaddiv**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    #email = Email.objects.all()
    squid_status = Squid.objects.filter(fecha__gte=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).values_list('user', flat=True).distinct().count()
    email_status = Email_org.objects.filter(fecha__gte=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).values_list('msgid', flat=True).distinct().count()
    incidencias_nav_status = Incidencia.objects.filter(fecha__gte=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).values_list('id', flat=True).distinct().count()
    incidencias_mial_status = Incidencia_email.objects.filter(fecha__gte=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).values_list('id', flat=True).distinct().count()
    incidencias_status = incidencias_nav_status + incidencias_mial_status
    return render(request, 'panel/loaddiv.html',{'email_status':email_status, 'squid_status':squid_status, 'incidencias_status':incidencias_status})
```

**View de Django para mostrar en templeta de dashboard**

```
@login_required
def profile2(request):
#email = Email.objects.all()
squid_status = Squid.objects.filter(fecha__gte=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).values_list('user', flat=True).distinct().count()
email_status = Email_org.objects.filter(fecha__gte=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).values_list('msgid', flat=True).distinct().count()
#incidencias_nav_status = Incidencia.objects.filter(fecha__gte=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).values_list('id', flat=True).distinct().count()
#incidencias_mial_status = Incidencia_email.objects.filter(fecha__gte=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).values_list('id', flat=True).distinct().count()
return render(request, 'panel/profile2.html')
```

**Javascript** en el template que muestra toda la informacion

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
  $('#alerta_incidencias').load('/loaddiv');//actualizas el div
  }, 1000 );
  });
</script>
```

**HTML**en la pagina donde se actualizan los datos

```
<div id="alerta_incidencias">
 <div class="widget red-bg p-lg text-center">
 <div class="m-b-md">
 <i class="fa fa-bell fa-4x"></i>
 <h1 class="m-xs">{{incidencias_status}} </h1>
 <h3 class="font-bold no-margins">
  Incidencia{{incidencias_status|pluralize}}  
  registrada{{incidencias_status|pluralize}}
 </h3>
 <h4 class="font-bold no-margins"><a  href="{%url 'incidencias' %}">          
 Detalles...</a></h4>
 </div>
 </div>
```

No logro que el templete cargue los datos desde "loaddiv"
A mi entender estoy pasando mal los parametros de la url en el javascript

Saludos

Comment: puedes incluir lo que tienes en loaddiv?

Comment: El codigo HTML es el que esta en el "loaddiv"

Comment: Yo no veo porque la etiqueta [tag:django] sea relevante. Parece un problema exclusivo de jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Primero, no queda claro el uso de las vistas profile y profile2. Además, deberías aclarar en tu mensaje que el html mostrado corresponde con loaddiv (lo cual aclaraste en los comentarios, pero ya que editaste la pregunta, preferible si haces que la pregunta quede mejor).

**Interpretación original de tu programa:**

Ahora bien, respecto al problema, entiendo que el javascript genera una petición al servidor por el recurso llamado **loaddiv**, y entonces tu server debería responder ejecutando una vista, si es que existe una ruta para **loaddiv** en urls.py. Supongo que profile2 responde al llamado de loaddiv, pero el resultado de ejecutar profile2 es el resultado del método render, ¿qué hace el método render?, [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) lo indica la documentación: retorna un objeto HttpResponse, resultante de combinar el contenido del html indicado con los datos del contexto enviado (no estás enviando nada).

**Nueva interpretación de tu programa:**

Al llamar a **loaddiv** se ejecuta la vista profile, que retorna un objeto HttpResponse con los datos obtenidos por las instrucciones contenidas en él. Ahora la duda es ¿qué relación existe entre los archivos loaddiv.html y profile2.html?, ¿dónde está ubicado el javascript?

Normalmente no utilizo esa forma de efectuar llamadas entre cliente y servidor, y considero que tiene un defecto: ¿qué pasa si HttpResponse devuelve un resultado inesperado?, pues ese resultado inesperado será cargado en el div que estás actualizando.

Comment: Puedes echarle un vistazo ahora?

Comment: Ok, edito un poco mi respuesta, para actualizarla.

Comment: Lo que me sucede es que entiendo bien la logica, usando los templates y vistas de Django, para pasar los datos a jquery. Usando solo html y funciona, pero al intentar hacerlo con Django no se exactamente a quien llamar en .load()

Comment: Lo que debes aclarar es quién llama a profile y quién a profile2, y qué relación existe entre loaddiv.html y profile2.html. El javascript llama a la ruta '/loaddiv', pero no se sabe quién atiende esa ruta; y desconozco si el devolver un objeto HttpResponse puede generarte algún inconveniente.

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo y debbugueando el codigo encontre que todo el problema venia ya que estaba cargando el jquery al final del codigo en vez de hacerlo en el hearder...

Al solucionar esto ya me funciona todo a la perfeccion... 
Saludos y muchas gracias...